# How to construct a set-based query for a subset?

Tags: sql, algorithm

I have a DB of the following structure (picture shows simplified version)

[image]

How should I construct a query to get only those recipees, that can be cooked, i.e. for each ingredient in a receipe requiredQuaintity > availableQuantity?

I tried this:

```
SELECT r.Name
FROM
   Receipe r
   JOIN RecipeIngredients ri ON ri.RecipeID = r.Id
   JOIN Ingredients i ON i.ID = ri.IngredientsId
WHERE
   ri.RequiredQuantity - i.AvailableQuantity > 0
```

but am not sure this is correct as I think this will only return available ingredients. How should I modify above query to produce only receipees where each of ingredient is available?
Thank you for help

---- Edit ----

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT r.Name
FROM
(
    SELECT   r.Name AS Name
             r.Id AS Id
           , CASE (
                WHEN (ri.RequiredQuantity - i.AvailableQuantity >= 0)
                THEN 1
             ) AS Available
    FROM
       Receipe r
       JOIN RecipeIngredients ri ON ri.RecipeID = r.Id
       JOIN Ingredients i ON i.ID = ri.IngredientsId
    WHERE
           ri.RequiredQuantity - i.AvailableQuantity >= 0  
    GROUP BY
       r.Id
) AS results
WHERE
    // count of ingredients with value 1 for each recipe == count of all required ingredients for this recipe
```

however I am not sure how to write the last line of above code

Comment: Looks like a [Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) query to me. besides the (external) link, there are lots of similar questions in the DBA.SE site (and in the main SO site.)

Comment: Why did you delete the DBA.SE question?

Comment: @ypercube because of complete lack of interest on DBA.SE I moved question here

Comment: You left the question for less than 1 hour? The DBA site offers better answers usually (with less speed I guess). Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @ypercube Can I leave question on both sites then?

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't mean that. One question is better. If you feel the question is better at this site, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing right now is to join in the recipe items (which duplicates the recipe data) and then distinct the duplication away. That is an anti-pattern. It does not capture your intent and makes the query harder to pull off.

Reformulate the query. What you want is all recipes where for all items the quantity condition holds. That is to say "there exists no items for which the condition does not hold".

```
select *
from recipes r
where not exist (
 select *
 from RecipeIngredients ri
 JOIN Ingredients i ON i.ID = ri.IngredientsId
 where
  r.id = ri.recipeid --join condition
  and not (ri.RequiredQuantity - i.AvailableQuantity >= 0) --quantity condition
)
```

Comment: @ypercube how could a required ingredient be missing in the ingredients table? That would violate database consistency. IngredientsId would point to a not existing ingredient.

Comment: usr is correct in his comment - every time new ingredient is added to a recipe, it will be saved in Ingredients table ... not sure about whole query though

Comment: @usr in the query, "from recipeitems" did you mean "from RecipeIngredients"?

Comment: @Macin yeah, don't take that code too literally. The idea is what's important.

Comment: @usr sure, can't test it now, but will try as soon as I get back home ;) Your query looks nice

Answer (score 1):

The following query first gets the number of required ingredients and available ingredients. If the # of required ingredients = # of available ingredients, then the recipe is selected.

```
SELECT 
    R.*
FROM Recipe R
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT 
    RI.RecipeID,
    Count(RI.IngredientsID) Required_Ingredients,
    SUM
    (CASE
        WHEN I.AvailableQuantity > RI.RequiredQuantity THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) Available_Ingredients  
FROM RecipeIngredients RI
INNER JOIN Ingredients I ON RI.IngredientsID = I.ID
GROUP BY RI.RecipeID
) Availability
ON R.ID = Availability.RecipeID
WHERE Availability.Required_Ingredients = Availability.Available_Ingredients
```